# Eclipse and gsl library - cannot find -lgsl_sf_bessel

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, gsl

I have a problem with eclipse and gsl library. Standard problem but in my case still not working. I have the following settings but this is incorrect. How change settings to compile my project?

[Eclipse settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELIwM.png)